# Qual a vantagem de assinar um commit com uma chave GPG?

Tags: git

- O que muda de um commit assinado e verificado para um commit sem assinatura?
- Qual a vantagem de assinar os commits com a chave GPG?

Answer (score 11):

GPG é um sistema de encriptação ponta a ponta utilizando pares, neste sistema os dados são encriptados no envio e decriptados no recebimento. Também é utilizado em assinaturas digitais "para que a integridade e o remetente da mensagem possam ser verificados".

Utilizar GPG protege seus dados de interceptação e também de um possível falso commit. Assim quem vê seu status de commit como "assinado" terá mais confiança em executar um código seu.

Resumindo:

• **O que muda de um commit assinado e verificado para um commit sem assinatura?**

Em aplicativos tipo github e similares, seu commit aparece um status adicional de "verificado".

**• Qual a vantagem de assinar os commits com a chave GPG?**

1. Evita interceptação do commit e falso commit em seu nome.
2. Fornece garantia para quem baixa seu código e o executa.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você assina um *commit* com o GPG, o GitHub coloca um status de "verificado", ou seja, os usuários saberão que é uma versão oficial, além disso, ele é compatível com a [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), o padrão da IETF.

Eu falei do GitHub, mais você pode usar em outros como o Bitbucket.

Usar o GPG (*GNU Privacy Guard* - GnuPG) aumenta a credibilidade do seu código, porque o usuário terá a "certeza" (lembre-se que nenhuma criptografia é 100%) de que não vem um vírus junto com o projeto ou ele de alguma forma foi modificado para desviar dados, não muito difícil, já vi alguns no GitHub (sem o GPG).

Ele possui interoperabilidade (capacidade de se comunicar) com o OpenPGP, então você poderia fazer a migração do PGP para o GPG.

Em relação a atualização do projeto, ele é parte da *Free Software Foundation*, e tem o patrocínio do governo Alemão, então temos atualizações para solucionar *bugs* e falhas de segurança por mais alguns anos ai, isso é uma grande vantagem em relação ao PGP.